# D3 Chart Legend, Bars not appearing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I cannot seem to get the Bars series to appear in the legend on my chart. Both line charts appear in the Legend OK. I have a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/E4av2/).

I then want to allow the user to click on individual legends and have these lines / bars appear/disappear from the chart as a transition, but have not found any examples of this other than NVD3.js, which I do not want to use. Could you point me to an example you may know of so I can learn from it.

Please click on the "Create Chart button first, so you can see the chart generated.

HTML code is:

```
<input id="clickMe1" type="button" value="Create Chart" onclick='createMainPerfChart()' />
<input id="clickMe2" type="button" value="Update Chart" onclick='updateMainPerfChart()' />
<div id="msg"></div>
<div style="margin-top:120px;">
    <svg id="mainchart"></svg>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the implementation of the legend for this. Specifically, you need to attach a click handler that, based on which circle is clicked, fades out the bars and the other line. The following code achieves this.

```
.on("click", function(d) {
                var op = d.hidden ? 1 : 0;
                d3.selectAll("rect.bar").transition().attr("opacity", op);
                if(d.key == "Cumulative Output") {
                    d3.select("path.TGTLine").transition().attr("opacity", op);
                } else {
                    d3.select("path.CABLine").transition().attr("opacity", op);
                }
                d.hidden = !d.hidden;
            });
```

I'm storing the current state in `.hidden` here to know whether to fade in or fade out. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E4av2/40/).

Comment: Hey Lars, THANK YOU!!! Couple of questions though: (1) The bars (blue circle) does not appear in the legend when the chart is created / updated. (2) I am looking to remove the series that is clicked, rather than the other series (the ones not clicked). You are a STAR and I am amazed about your ongoing tutorials!

Comment: Hmm, (1) seems to be a bug in the legend implementation you're using. To do (2), you just need to reverse the logic in the click handler --http://jsfiddle.net/E4av2/41/

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks again... Interestingly, if you click "create chart" twice, the second time brings the bars blue circle into the legend... I will have more of a play. THANK YOU!